# Extract Numbers from a String in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to extract a series of number from a string in excel.

```
ZERINER JERNIGAN                                       123-45-6789
```

The formula I used:

```
right(trim(A1), len(trim(A1)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},trim(A1)&"0123456789")) + 1)
```

which it will return `123-45-6789`

---

But when I run into example like

```
3ES INNOVATION INC                                     12-3456789
```

The function will capture 9 as the first number instead of 1.

Is there any way to capture only right side of the string (`12-3456789`) and ignore whatever starts from the left, even if its a digit?

Comment: Would you be open to using vba? If yes, then it's pretty easy

Comment: Yes I am open to VBA

Comment: I deleted my answer because I either misread your question or you modified it. What if your string is something like "423AB 97" - would you just want the 97?

Comment: Yes correct. so in this case 3ES INNOVATION INC 98-0485843 I would just want 98-0485843

Comment: Are the left part and right part of the text always separated by more than one space? Basically, we need some **delimeter** which will consistently separate left and right side. Also, can there be more than one space on the "left side"?

Comment: Seems like using RegEx could also be a solution here. Another solution would be to get the string from the right till the first space encountered from the right. Pretty decent examples around on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in B1 use:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255))
```

Check if there are numbers:

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0
```

Combine the two in an IF:

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255))))>0,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",255)),255)),"")
```

Comment: one question - if the text is "T GRANT ANDERSON" and there is no digits in the end, what should I change in the current function to make sure that it returns nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, e.g. =FNumbers(A1) or =FNumbers("3ES INNOVATION INC 98-0485843").

I'm not sure all possibilites have been enumerated. I have assumed, as Rawrplus suggests, that there is at least a space separating numbers at the beginning from later on.

```
Function FNumber(s As String) As String

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = ".\s(\d+-*\d+)"
    If .Test(s) Then FNumber = .Execute(s)(0).submatches(0)
End With

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: It returns 9! So in order to show the rest of number do I just enter a very large number for num_chars like MID(MID(A1,2,500),MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},MID(A1,2,500)&"0123456789")),50) in the end?

Comment: The comment above applies to a deleted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic formula solution is added.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(" - ";TRUE;IFERROR(INT(MID(A1; {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}; 1));""))}
```

[image]